# How to bind/unbind usb device in PyUsb?

Tags: python, usb, pyusb

I need to on/off several usb devices on my python script.
Can i bind and unbind usb devices with PyUsb?

I can do it with shell commands:
Power off:
`echo "device_nuber" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind`
Power on:
`echo "device_nuber" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind`

How execute the same in python script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `attach_kernel_driver` and `detach_kernel_driver`.

```py
import usb.core
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x1234,idProduct=0x5678)
# unbind interface 0
dev.detach_kernel_driver(0)
# bind interface 0
dev.attach_kernel_driver(0)
```

Comment: Thanks! It's help me.

Comment: Does this behave as un/bind? I do see un/mount occurs with this code (confirmed by `lsblk` on Ubuntu) but the device remains bound/connected (confirmed by `lsusb`).

Comment: Nevermind. Confirmed this works https://stackoverflow.com/a/70311497/577001