# Un/bind a USB device via Python (preferably by PyUSB)

Tags: linux, usb, pyusb

Is there a way with [pyusb](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb) to unbind a USB device?

I know using the following `bash` the USB is unbound.

```
DEVICE=$(grep 064f /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/idVendor | tr '/' ' ' | awk '{ print $5 }')
/bin/bash -c "echo $DEVICE >/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind"
```

But for various reasons I like to move away from `bash` and switch to Python, and ideally avoid maintaining my custom, complicated logic. So using a existing library makes sense to me.

Selected answer in [stackoverflow.com#q54863367](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54877413/577001) suggests `detach_kernel_driver` to work for this purpose, but I don't see that happening on my environment; It does unmount the volume in the designated USB device (confirmed by watching the disk space on the USB disappears in `lsblk`'s output) but I still see that OS detects the USB device.

```
$ ipython
In [7]: import usb
   ...: dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x064f, idProduct=0x03f3)
In [8]: dev.detach_kernel_driver(0)
```

```
$ watch lsusb
:
Bus 002 Device 043: ID 064f:03f3 WIBU-Systems AG CmStick/M (article no. 1011)
```

### Environment

Linux (At the time of writing, Ubuntu 16.04 (I know EoLed) or 18.04. But environment shouldn't be a limiting factor. Open for available solutions regardless the version.

---

UPDATE: My usecase requires mimicing removal of USB device. We've been happy with the operation typically called as `un/bind`, and also happy with the `bash` solution to realize `un/bind`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd close OP but coudln't choose an appripriate reason so answer by myself instead.

As I concluded myself with a help from the maintainer in [pyusb#399](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/issues/399#issuecomment-985965383) I found I was misunderstood. Using `detach_kernel_driver` as suggested in [stackoverflow.com#q54863367](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54877413/577001) worked for my purpose as well.

Answer (score 1):

A quick [search](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/search?q=unbind) of the PyUSB code makes it seem like there is no feature for binding or unbinding.  So PyUSB is not the answer.

However, you don't need to use Bash to unbind a device.  Python has a standard library that lets you get directory listings, read files, and write to files, so you can just use Python's standard library instead of Bash.

Comment: Thx for confirming about `PyUSB`. To clarify I added update to OP, IINM I need to un/bind USB and we've only found `bash`-way to achieve that.

Comment: Repeating the point I made in my second paragraph:  your Bash script isn't doing anything too complicated.  It's reading a directory, reading some files, and then writing a little bit of text to a file.  These things are simple to do in Python.  Have you tried making a pure Python implementation?  What exact step are you stuck on?

Comment: Just looking at what your Bash script does, I can tell tell that the first step would be to get a directory listing of `/sys/bus/usb/devices`.  Then descend into every subdirectory of it (each subdirectory represents a device).  Then read the `idVendor` file in each of those subdirectories.  Then figure out what the correct `DEVICE` string is.  Then open the `unbind` file and write that string to it.  Then close the `unbind` file.

Comment: Oh! I now know why you mentioned those standard libs. Sounds reasonable enough. I'll try and report back.